# Triangle function on angles

Tags: python-2.7, function

I need a function that works on angles (degrees for the example, but it may be radians as well) with the following (it must be continuous, I only write down some key values to understand the behavior):

```
any_function(angle):

  0-> 0.0
 45-> 0.5
 90-> 1.0
135-> 0.5
180-> 0.0
225->-0.5
270->-1.0
335->-0.5
360-> 0.0
```

This is a simple triangular wave.

Does anything already exist in some modules or do I need to create it on my own?
For example like this (quick and dirty):

```
def toTriangle(angle):
if angle < 90 and angle >= 0:
    t = (angle/90.)
elif angle <= 180 and angle >= 90:
    t = 2-(angle/90.)
elif angle <= 270 and angle >= 180:
    t = -(3-(angle/90.))
else:
    t = -(4-(angle/90.))
return t
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks DeepSpace for your suggestion but it doesn't work out of the box:

```
from scipy.signal import sawtooth
sawtooth(0)
Out[4]: array(-1.0)
```

Here's a less quick-n-dirty solution:

```
def toTriangle(angle):
    import math
    tr = 1-4*math.fabs(0.5-math.modf(0.25+0.5*angle%(2*math.pi)/math.pi)[0] )
    return t
```

( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleWave.html )